# Ajax posting succesful but Django receiving as Null value

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Ajax sent data successful but Django function receiving it as Null Value.... tried all possible ways for days now yet same result....Please this is delaying me from submission date.

have  tried trying to send in json format but it rejects it

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "results/",
          data: {'datum': 1000},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert("You will now be redirected.");
            window.location.href = "results/";
            },
          error: function(request, status, error, data){
            console.log(error);
        },

  });
```

Django view

```
def thistry(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':

     dat = request.GET.get('datum')
     dee = 9
     return  render(request, 'studentapp/rough2.html', {'dat': dat,     'dee':dee})
```

django url

```
path('weekly/teachers/results/', views.thistry, name='first_page_weekly'),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def thistry(request):
    dat = request.GET.get('datum')
    dee = 9
    return JsonResponse({'dat': dat, 'dee': dee})
```